# Ionic 2 Native Facebook Plugin errors when grabbing User profile picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic2

I have a snippet of code in my Ionic 2 app that is supposed to grab the Facebook profile of the user after they have successfully logged on. I've verified that the request path `/me` returns data associated with the user, however when I set the request path to `/me/picture`, I get an error: `There was an error making the graph call.`

Here is my code:

```
if(this.platform.is('cordova')) {

      Facebook.login([
        'public_profile',
        'user_friends',
        'email'
      ]).then((result) => {
        Facebook.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,cover', []).then(data => {

          // Create the user object
          let user = {
            access_token: result.authResponse.accessToken,
            display_name: data.name,
            email: data.email,
            facebook_id: data.id,
            cover_photo: data.cover.source,
          }


          Facebook.api(`me/picture`, []).then(data => {
            user['profile_photo'] = data.url;
            this.loginWithFacebook(user);
          }, error => { this.user = JSON.stringify(error)});
        })
      },
      error => {
        this.user = JSON.stringify(error);
      })
    }
```

Am I missing something? I've even tried doing `/{user-id}/picture` and still receive an error. Anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default this edge will return a 302 redirect to the picture image. To get access to the data about the picture, please include redirect=false in your query.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

For example: `Facebook.api('me/picture?redirect=false', [])...`